# Using VB Application.Ontime method with variable times that are read from an excel range

Tags: excel, vba

using the VB Applcation.Ontime method has been discussed here several times, but not in the way the I would like to use it. I am using it to run an API python script to collect data from a website. The time is read from a range, with the idea that after each time he MyMacro is run, it will increment to the next time, the next cell is read for the next scheduled event.

Events are not scheduled to a set interval, (which would be nice) but because this is time sensitive, I have to read the time in.

"i" is dimensioned at the top of the module as Long
As discussed here in many threads, I am using one sub to call another sub, the call the first sub again to create the loop.

The idea is the first time the timer runs is read from AH2, then second time from AH3, third time is AH4 and so on.

I have tried many different scenarios including Do Loops & For Loops and cant get it right. For Loops works a real treat and created many instances to run the batch file. Bit of mind snap on my part with that one. So I have reverted to old school of i=i+1 and still cant get it right.

The issue is that "i" is not incrementing and so the loop is not being created.

Setting a fixed time interval, to define the frequency is not a suitable solution.

I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am missing.

Thank you in advance for your help. The code is as follows.

```
Sub RunAPITimer()
Dim TimeToRun As Date, CellTime As Date

'Reset i for the next day
If Now() < TimeValue("00:09:00") Then i = 0

'incase i is empty, set i to zero
If IsEmpty(i) Then i = 0
        With Sheet10
            CellTime = .Range("AH" & 2 + i).Value
            TimeToRun = TimeValue(Format(CellTime, "hh:mm:ss"))
            Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "myMacro"
        End With
End Sub


Sub myMacro()
Dim batchFilePath As String

'Set the file path
batchFilePath = "C:\XXX\a.bat"

' Run the batch file and capture the process ID
Dim shellResult As Double
Dim shellProcess As Object
Set shellProcess = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shellResult = shellProcess.Run(batchFilePath, vbHide, True)

        With Sheet63 'API Timer Log
            'record when the API was run
             irow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & irow).Value = "Timer ran at:"
            .Range("C" & irow).Value = Now()
        End With

'increment the row counter
i = i + 1
Call RunAPITimer
End Sub
```

This is my first question on this forum, so please excuse my naïveté with it's use.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue.
The problem was with the format of the date.
Once I changed the syntax to:

TimeToRun = CDate(.Range("AH" & 2 + i).Value)

everything started working correctly.